# Samsung Deep Sleep Workaround (Content Provider vs Bound Service)

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, sleep, samsung-mobile

I am working on a library integrated into multiple apps that need to 'talk' to each other to get a specific value.
This is an issue on Samsung since the apps can be put into Deep Sleep and cannot be queried.
Right now the library uses Content Provider which seems to not work at all if in Deep Sleep.

However, a workaround I found was to use a 'Bound' Service.
I am not super familiar with them, or services in general, but how come Content Provider will not work for an application in Deep Sleep, but a Bound Service seems to work?

Appreciate discussion around this.
Is Bound Service a valid workaround to a Deep Sleeping application?
The other workaround I found was to basically just call startActivity and launch an empty host activity that closes itself with a transparent UX, which effectively takes the application out of Deep Sleep